# Resources not being cached (304 not modified)

Tags: caching, nginx, response

I want to get a 304 not modified or a 200 cache response, but I am always getting a 200 OK response every single time. I am using nginx and firefox developer to check the response.

Below the response headers:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000, public
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="catHuis.jpg"
Content-Length: 6640
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Mon, 12 Jan 2015 13:45:33 GMT
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 12 Jan 2015 12:40:00 GMT
Pragma: public
Server: nginx/1.2.1
```

I am getting 200 OK's with those headers. Obviously the date is super far in the future, but I was desperate and tested it with very far expire headers. Can anyone point me in the direction? I must be missing something.

Here is the current nginx configuration:

```
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name mydomain.com;
autoindex off;
expires max;
access_log off;
add_header Pragma public;
add_header Cache-Control public;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try location rule for static assets like this:

```
location ~* \.(txt|ico|css|js|bmp|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|swf|avi|mp4|webm|pdf|mel|rar|zip|bin)$ {
  expires max;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that. There is no extension in the URL, so the location will not match any of those extensions... Must say though that I currently have those three rules in the main configuration (on all files). I added my nginx config to my first post.